# C# specialization of generic extension methods

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have the following extension methods for my `MessageBus`:

```
public static class MessageBusMixins
{
    public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(
        this IObservable<T> observable,
        MessageBus bus)
    where T:class
    {
        ...
    }

    public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>( 
        this IObservable<Maybe<T>> observable,
        MessageBus bus)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

which compiles fine. However when I try to use it:

```
IObservable<Maybe<string>> source = ...;
MessageBus bus = ...;

source.Subscribe(bus);
```

I get the error that neither of the two candidate methods
are most specific. However I thought that `Maybe<T>` would
be *more* specific than `T` or is that not correct?

**EDIT**

It gets curiouser because if I call the extension method
explicitly then:

```
MessageBus.SubscribeTo(source, bus);
```

Then it works and picks the correct method.

Comment: You can make it work as expected: `public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>( 
        this IObservable<T> observable,
        MessageBus bus) where T : Maybe<T>`

Comment: @2kay Generic constraints are not part of the candidate resolution process, so that won't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can fix it by specifying the type argument:

```
source.Subscribe<string>(bus);
```

... as that's now only the second method is applicable.

Otherwise, the compiler could call either of:

```
source.Subscribe<string>(bus);
source.Subscribe<Maybe<string>>(bus);
```

If you think the first is more specific than the second, you'll have to find the rule in the C# specification which says so :) It's not an unreasonable expectation, but I don't *think* the normal "more specific" conversions apply to *type parameters* as well as regular parameters.

So for example, in section 7.5.3.2 of the C# 4 spec ("Better Function Member") there a rule about:

> - Otherwise if M<sub>P</sub> has more specific parameter types than M<sub>Q</sub>, then M<sub>P</sub> is better than M<sub>Q</sub>. [... lots of details about less/more specific ...]

... but there's no similar point about type parameters. (The second about normal parameters talks about type arguments, but that's within the parameter types themselves.)

Another alternative is to simply give the methods different names. Do they have subtly different behaviour? If so, why not make that really obvious via the naming? You really don't want someone to get the wrong behaviour just because they were surprised about which overload was called.

Comment: Hi Jon. I've updated the question with calling the extension method directly which gives different results. Why are extension methods unable to specialize whereas direct calls are. Does this fit with your understanding of the standard.

Comment: In this case I will go with the direct call as it is compile time safe for me.